# Express.js: res.render() does not send data when wrapped in promise chain

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, promise, ejs

**I recently started refactoring older callback-hell routes to use promises.** *(Note: the refactor is not complete so some of the following code is ugly)*

Doing so broke my `res.render()` function.

- I am using EJS for my render engine.
- Most of my promise chains are built off of MongoDB / Mongoose queries.

The basic app structure is a complex survey / quiz that sorts users into different categories. It stores their info and renders a custom EJS page at the end. Here's how the final call works, basically:

```
         mongoose.model('Result')
             .findOne({quizId: req.query.id})
             .then(getPageData)
             .then(renderPage)
             .catch(errorHandler)
```

Simple enough, in theory.

Relevant functions:

```
    let getPageData = (mongooseResult) => {

      let resultsPage;
      let analyticsData;

      if (mongooseResult.answers.section1.question1.answer != null && mongooseResult.answers.section1.question1.answer != undefined){
          let resultsPage = WP.getPage(wp_pages_data, 'slug', mongooseResult.coreFit);
          let analyticsData = {
            quizId: mongooseResult.quizId,
            coreFit: mongooseResult.coreFit,
            secondFit: mongooseResult.secondFit,
            degree: mongooseResult.answers.section1.question1.answer,
            year: mongooseResult.answers.section1.question2.answer,
            concentration: mongooseResult.answers.section1.question3.answer,
            views: mongooseResult.views,
          }

        mongooseResult.views++;
        mongooseResult.save();

        return [resultsPage, analyticsData, mongooseResult];
      } else {
        throw new Error('S1Q1 IS UNDEFINED');
      }
    };
    let renderPage = ([resultsPage, analyticsData, mongooseResult]) => {
      if (resultsPage != null && resultsPage != undefined){

        // WHY IS MY RENDER NOT WORKING???
        res.render('templates/' + mongooseResult.coreFit,  Object.assign({}, WP.get_WP_data(resultsPage), getPartials(mongooseResult.modules), analyticsData), (err, html) => {if (err) console.log(err); else res.send(html);});
      } else {
        throw new Error('GETTING PAGE DATA RETURNED UNDEFINED');
      }
    };
```

Incoming requests are first routed to a `/submit` POST route - which manipulates some data, stores it all in the DB, then does `res.redirect()` to the `/results?id=12345` GET route, which runs the logic above.

What's funky is that the `render()` actually fires; the callback ( `(err, html) => {if (err) console.log(err); else res.send(html);}` ) sends rendered HTML to IF YOU HIT THE ROUTE A SECOND TIME.

Completing the survey does NOT generate a response; but it DOES successfully store all our info in the DB and console.logs the ID to which the client request should redirect. Hitting the GET route with this generated ID / URL, literally by copy-pasting it, renders just fine.

Swapping the render for a simple `res.send('wtf')` works - an actual response is sent to the client. *(in this case the string 'wtf' ... )*

The response just doesn't send back data. I don't get it. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Strangely enough, hitting the route manually vs the redirect from my earlier POST request produce different results with a simple `res.send('wtf mate')`.

*Hitting the GET route and passing in a previously existing ID to the req.query manually:*[image]

*Hitting the GET route AFTER the `res.redirect()` call from the prior POST request:*[image]

This might be more an Express request type mismatch issue? Why would a `res.redirect('/results?id=someString')` call mutate the URL vs sending back a string / HTML?

Comment: why You pass anonymous function as last argument? `res.render` and sends it to client. I don't see necessity to do additional `res.send`.

Comment: You're right - In this case for debugging only; I wanted to see whether adding the extra callback explicitly did anything to help - or if there was a secret `err` being swallowed behind the scenes.

Comment: Since you're using code like `mongooseResult.save()`, are you sure that the `POST /submit` actually _waits_ for the database saves/updates to be completed before it redirects?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your update, it sounds like your `res.send()` call is being interpreted strangely on the client side. POST request should not affect the URL bar unless you've specifically told it to - have you checked where the client initially sends this request?

My guess - since you say that the routing code you posted above is being hit from `res.redirect()` on a prior POST route - is that there is client-side logic expecting a `response` object to be a URL string, and hitting the GET route for the first time via your redirect carries over this response object. So that the client is attempting to insert a massive string of HTML into the URL bar.

In this case, hitting the GET route manually, like you said, would simply render the HTML from `res.render()` by default - but your initial hit from the `res.redirect()` might not.

Comment: DOH! You nailed it.... Here is part of my client-side AJAX:
`success: (res) => { window.location = res; }` So, yeah, you're right. Since `res.render()` returns an HTML string, the URL bar didn't have a clue what to do with it. But the default GET behavior expects HTML - so manually pinging the route behaved correctly. Instead of doing `res.redirect()`, I just did a `res.send('results?id=12345')` - which redirects the client to my GET route and it all is well with the world! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to debug issue by testing code parts.

I've few clues, one of them is that `'templates/' + result.coreFit` does not have template.
Try to check `coreFit` value if there is a file in `templates` folder with same value-name.

Try this code and tell me if it's working:

```
const 
  _ = require('lodash'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose');

const getQuizResultById = quizId => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const 
            Result = mongoose.model('Result'),
            query = {
                quizId
            };

        Result
            .findOne(query)
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(reject);
    });
};

const getPageData = result => {
    if (_.get(result, 'answers.section1.question1.answer')) {
        let resultsPage = WP.getPage(wp_pages_data, 'slug', result.coreFit);
        let 
        analyticsData = _.pick(result, ['quizId', 'coreFit', 'secondFit', 'views']);
        analyticsData.degree = _.get(result, 'answers.section1.question1.answer');
        analyticsData.year = _.get(result, 'answers.section1.question2.answer');        
        analyticsData.concentration = _.get(result, 'answers.section1.question3.answer');

        result.views++;
        result.save();

        return [resultsPage, analyticsData, result];
    }

    throw new Error('S1Q1 IS UNDEFINED');
}

const renderPage = ([resultsPage, analyticsData, result], res) => {
    if (resultsPage) {
        return res.render(
            'templates/' + result.coreFit,  
            Object.assign({}, WP.get_WP_data(resultsPage), getPartials(result.modules), analyticsData), 
            (err, html) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return res.status(500).send('Ooopsss...');
                }
                res.send(html);
            });
    } 

    throw new Error('GETTING PAGE DATA RETURNED UNDEFINED');
};

router.get('/results', (req, res) => {
    getQuizResultById(req.query.id)
        .then(getPageData)
        .then(data => {
           renderPage(data, res);
        })
        .catch(errorHandler);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @num8er ! Turns out it was a terrible client-side oversight on my part during the refactor process. Check out Lars' answer above - the critical clue was how my URL bar re-routed when hitting the GET route as part of a redirect when submitting the final survey.... Totally spaced this piece since 99% of the refactor is server-side